# Port information in skb doesn't match with the tcpdump's one

Tags: c, linux, networking, linux-kernel, network-programming

I catch network packet in */net/core/dev.c* file at function `__netif_receive_skb_core()`. I parse the packet and fetch `src_port`, `dest_port`, etc. I have taken tcpdump at any interface. But port information of tcpdump does not match with my fetched port information. I don't understand why.

```
orig_dev = skb->dev;
eth = eth_hdr(skb);
__be16 src_port = 0, dest_port = 0; 

if (skb->protocol == htons(ETH_P_IP))
{
    ih = ip_hdr(skb);
    proto_num = ih->protocol;
    switch (ih->protocol)
    {
    case IPPROTO_TCP:
    {
        struct tcphdr *th = tcp_hdr(skb);
        src_port = th->source;
        dest_port = th->dest;
        break;
    }
    case IPPROTO_UDP:
    {
        struct udphdr *uh = udp_hdr(skb);
        src_port = uh->source;
        dest_port = uh->dest;
        break;
    }
    default:
        src_port = 0;
        dest_port = 0;
    }

    fast_node = NULL;
    fast_node = (struct fast_pktlist *)kzalloc(sizeof(*fast_node), GFP_KERNEL);

    if (fast_node)
    {

        fast_node->protocol_num = proto_num;
        strcpy(fast_node->in_interface, orig_dev->name);
        fast_node->orgsrc_ip = ih->saddr;
        fast_node->orgdest_ip = ih->daddr;
        memcpy(fast_node->orgsrc_mac, eth->h_source, 6);

        fast_node->org_srcport = src_port;
        fast_node->org_destport = dest_port;

        INIT_LIST_HEAD(&fast_node->_list);
        list_add_tail(&fast_node->_list, &FAST_HEAD);
    }
    else
    {
        printk("can not allocate memory at line number = %d\n", __LINE__);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"catch packet in function"*? You patched the kernel i.e. added your code to this function?

Comment: yes I add my code in the kernel and want to load received skb info (srcport, destport etc) in a linklist. But srcport and destination port have no match with tcp dump at that time. For example I make many dns request. In tcp dump all of the requests have destination port 53 but in my linked list I got no packet with destination port 53.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see where and how you print or compare ports (perhaps you somewhere print `src_port` and `dest_port` or `fast_node->org_srcport` and `fast_node->org_destport` with `%u` specifier of `printk`).
But you must take into account that *port* in [TCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#TCP_segment_structure) and [UDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol#UDP_datagram_structure) headers is none 1-byte field (it has 2 bytes length), so it has [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). Specifically network byte order.
That is why  to see the port in host byte order while printing you should use special function to swap the bytes - [`ntohs()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.4.161/source/include/linux/byteorder/generic.h#L141) - network-to-host-short. Roughly speaking "short" means that is function is for 2-byte variables.

So finally if you need to print ports it should be something like:

```
printk(KERN_INFO "sport:%u dport:%u\n", ntohs(src_port), ntohs(dest_port));
```

and if you need to compare:

```
if (ntohs(dest_port) == 53)
```

BTW `network_header` and `transport_header` must be set by the time you access the headers through the `ip_hdr()` / `tcp_hdr()` / `udp_hdr()`, otherwise returned pointers could be invalid.

---

Also you must take care in how you allocating memory in different places inside kernel.
`__netif_receive_skb_core()` executes in *atomic* context, so you can't sleep here. [`GFP_KERNEL`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.4.161/source/include/linux/gfp.h#L197) flag allows some sleeping for `kmalloc()`, thus you have a bug. Change `GFP_KERNEL` to [`GFP_ATOMIC`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.4.161/source/include/linux/gfp.h#L194).

Comment: BTW network_header and transport_header must be set by the time you access the headers. I cannot understand. Please explain.

Comment: @Nayan `skb->network_header` and `skb->transport_header` offsets must me set properly by the network stack. If it was not set - `ip_hdr()` & co will return invalid pointers.
Thus you should embed your code to the right place where this offsets have been already set. I can’t know where your code is located because you didn't describe it in your question. So this is just a forewarning..

Comment: case IPPROTO_UDP:
    {
        struct udphdr *uh = udp_hdr(skb);
        src_port = uh->source;
        dest_port = uh->dest;printk(KERN_INFO "sport:%u dport:%u\n", ntohs(src_port), ntohs(dest_port));
        break;
    }src_port prints a fixed value(17664) for all packets. dest_port change with packets but why source port never change though in tcpdump I got different srcport.

Comment: @Nayan How exactly do you map packets in `tcpdump` with packets that you print from kernel?

Comment: I think a linux router receives all the packets in __netif_receive_skb_core function and send those packet with same destination port (same as the destination port while receive) through __dev_queue_xmit. Am I right or not?

Comment: Also you must take care in how you allocating memory in different places inside kernel.
__netif_receive_skb_core() executes in atomic context, so you can't sleep here. GFP_KERNEL flag allows some sleeping for kmalloc(), thus you have a bug. Change GFP_KERNEL to GFP_ATOMIC.@red0ct how can I know which functions execute in atomic context and which are not in atomic. So that I can allocate memory properly

Comment: @Nayan What does it mean *"I think"*? You should inspect source code and different articles in the Internet including stackoverflow. I can't explain you all the basics about Linux kernel in comments.
Also read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netfilter#/media/File:Netfilter-packet-flow.svg
then come here with exact questions.
`__netif_receive_skb_core` is input function and `__dev_queue_xmit` is the output.

Comment: @Nayan *"how can I know which functions execute in atomic context "* through inspecting Linux kernel sources and reading the comments. Also you must understand exactly the conditions of atomic context. E.g. the code executing while `rcu_read_lock()` is acquired must not sleep, the same thing is with `spin_lock` & co., you can't sleep in interrupts and so on. I think you are up to read [Robert Love book](https://www.amazon.com/Linux-Kernel-Development-Robert-Love/dp/0672329468)

Comment: @Nayan Read this article https://jvns.ca/blog/2017/03/19/getting-started-with-ftrace/ this may help you understand how packets are processed in Linux kernel. With `trace-cmd` you can obtain `function_graph` to see how packet travels through the kernel. It will be visibly.